# Как сохранять измененный текст в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton

У меня есть код, и при нажатии кнопки "Далее" меняется текст, как сделать что бы он сохранялся и при следующем входе появлялся уже измененный текст?
Мой код:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore, QtMultimedia
from PyQt5.Qt import *

MyApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
V = MyApp.desktop().screenGeometry()
h = V.height()
w = V.width()
try:
    from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QtWin
    myappid = 'mycompany.myproduct.subproduct.version'
    QtWin.setCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(myappid)
except ImportError:
    pass

class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.icon_1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        self.icon_1.addPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap("start.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 300))
        self.setIcon(self.icon_1)
        
        self.icon_2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        self.icon_2.addPixmap(
            QtGui.QPixmap("start_true.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(500, 300))

        self.setFixedSize(350, 220)
        
    def enterEvent(self, event):  
        self.setIcon(self.icon_2)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.setIcon(self.icon_1)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.num = 5
        self.text = None
        self._rect = QRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
        filename = 'music.mp3'
        fullpath = QtCore.QDir.current().absoluteFilePath(filename)
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(fullpath)
        content = QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(url)
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
        self.player.setMedia(content)
        self.player.setVolume(50)
        self.player.play()

        self.slider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        self.slider.setRange(0, 100)
        self.slider.setValue(50)
        self.slider.setGeometry(800, 720, 300, 70)
        self.slider.hide()
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.player.setVolume)

        def Button_Name(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('MS Serif', 14))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_2(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, size):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            btn_name.setText(text)
            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Gabriola', size))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            # btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Button_3(btn_name, text, px, resize, resize_2, move, move_2, color, mains):
            btn_name.setMouseTracking(True);
            if text == "Настройки громкости":
                btn_name.setCheckable(True)
                btn_name.setText(f'{text}: ({self.slider.value()})')
            else:
                btn_name.setText(text)

            btn_name.setStyleSheet(
                "color: " + color + "; border-radius: " + str(px) + "px")
            btn_name.setFont(QtGui.QFont('MS Serif', 14))
            btn_name.resize(resize, resize_2)
            btn_name.move(move, move_2)
            btn_name.clicked.connect(mains)

        def Image(lbl_name, move_1, move_2, resize_1, resize_2):
            lbl_name.setPixmap(self.pix)
            lbl_name.move(move_1, move_2)
            lbl_name.resize(resize_1, resize_2)

        self.lbl2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("image.jpg").scaled(w, h)
        Image(self.lbl2, 0, 0, w, h)
        self.lbl1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("System_image/textbox.png").scaled(w, int(h/4))
        Image(self.lbl1, 0, h-int(h/3), w, int(h/3+100))
        self.lbl11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/next.png").scaled(220, 70)
        Image(self.lbl11, w-270, h-130, 250, 85)
        self.btn_next_text = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_next_text, "", 5, 250, 85, w-270, h-130, "White", self.next)
        self.btn_next_text.close()

        self.lbl11.close()
        self.btn1 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_2(self.btn1, "Да", 10, 1000, 200, int(w/2-500), int(h/1.40), "White", 15)
        self.inv = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory_btn.png").scaled(156, 96)
        Image(self.inv, -30, int(h/2+50), 156, 96)
        self.btn31 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn31, "", 0, 156, 96, -30, int(h/2+50), "White", self.inventory)
        self.inv_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/inventory.png").scaled(w-150, h-84)
        Image(self.inv_open, 70, 40, w-150, h-84)
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn4, "", 5, 120, 120, int(w/1.18), int(h/10), "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn4.close()
        self.lbl20 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("System_image/Selection_menu.png").scaled(w, h)
        Image(self.lbl20, 0, 0, w, h)
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.mg_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("Button_image/Magazine.png").scaled(156, 96)
        Image(self.mg_open, -30, int(h/2-60), 156, 96)
        self.btn5 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn5, "", 0, 156, 96, -30, int(h/2-60), "White", self.event_log)

        self.btn6 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn6, "", 0, int(w/3), h, 0, 0, "White", self.notes)
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn7, "", 0, int(w/3), h, int(w/3), 0, "White", self.easter)
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn8, "", 0, int(w/3), h, int(w/3*2), 0, "White", self.tasks)
        self.btn8.close()
        self.notes_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Notes.png").scaled(w, h)
        Image(self.notes_open, 0, 0, w, h)
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn9, "", 5, 100, 100, int(w/1.13), int(h/20), "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn9.close()
        self.easter_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Easter.png").scaled(w, h)
        Image(self.easter_open, 0, 0, w, h)
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn10, "", 5, 100, 100, int(w/1.13), int(h/20), "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn10.close()

        self.tasks_open = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap("The_event_log/Tasks.png")
        Image(self.tasks_open, 0, 0, w, h)
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn11 = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn11, "", 5, 100, 100, int(w/1.13), int(h/20), "White", self.inventory_close)
        self.btn11.close()

        self.lbl2.close()
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

        self.btn_start = PushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_start, "", 20, 500, 200, int(w/2-175), int(h/5), "Black", self.start)

        self.btn_next = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_next, "Продолжить", 20, 300, 100, int(w/2-150), int(h/2), "Black", self.next_start)

        self.btn_select = QPushButton(self)
        Button_3(self.btn_select, "Настройки громкости", 20, 500, 100, int(w/2-250), int(h/1.5), "Black", self.volume_custom)

    def inventory(self):
        self.btn_next_text.close()
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.inv_open.show()
        self.btn4.show()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.btn6.close()

    def inventory_close(self):
        self.btn_next_text.show()
        self.lbl11.show()
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()

    def animations(self):
        animation = QPropertyAnimation(self)
        animation.setTargetObject(self.btn_name)
        animation.setPropertyName(b'pos')
        animation.setStartValue(QPoint(250, -200))
        animation.setEndValue(QPoint(250, 0))
        animation.setDuration(500)
        animation.start()

    def event_log(self):
        self.btn_next_text.close()
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.btn31.close()
        self.btn1.close()
        self.lbl1.close()
        self.inv.close()
        self.btn5.close()
        self.mg_open.close()
        self.lbl20.show()
        self.btn6.show()
        self.btn7.show()
        self.btn8.show()

    def notes(self):
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.notes_open.show()
        self.btn9.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def easter(self):
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.easter_open.show()
        self.btn10.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def tasks(self):
        self.lbl11.close()
        self.lbl20.close()
        self.tasks_open.show()
        self.btn11.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()

    def start(self):
        self.btn_next_text.show()
        self.lbl11.show()
        self.btn_next.close()
        self.btn1.show()
        self.lbl1.show()
        self.inv.show()
        self.inv_open.close()
        self.btn4.close()
        self.notes_open.close()
        self.btn9.close()
        self.mg_open.show()
        self.btn5.show()
        self.btn6.close()
        self.btn7.close()
        self.btn8.close()
        self.easter_open.close()
        self.btn10.close()
        self.btn11.close()
        self.tasks_open.close()
        self.btn31.show()
        self.lbl2.show()
        self.slider.close()
        self.btn_select.close()
        self.btn_start.close()

    def volume_custom(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        print(f'def volume_custom(): {sender.text()} - {sender.isChecked()}')

        if sender.isChecked():
            self.slider.show()
        else:
            self.slider.close()

        sender.setText(f'Настройки громкости: ({self.slider.value()})')

    def next_start(self):
        #тут действие нужно
        print()
    def next(self):
        self.btn1.setText("Нет")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('System_image/icon.png'))
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.setWindowTitle('Story Telling')
    ex.setWindowIcon(QIcon('System_image/icon.png'))
    ex.showFullScreen()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QSettings.html

Comment: задавайте текст по средством чтения из файла и изменения сохраняйте в файле

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо задавать текст по средством чтения из файла и изменения сохранять в файле

Пример возможного решения данной задачи:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Example(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(155, 118, 90, 18))
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(153, 253, 94, 29))
        self.pushButton.setText('Изменить')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.change)
        self.pushButton.click()

        self.resize(400, 400)
        self.show()

    def change(self):
        with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
            text = f.read()
            self.label.setText('Старый текст' if  text == '' else text)
            if text == '':
                with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
                    f.write('Новый текст')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```